# MySQL: using UNION vs multiple queries

Tags: mysql, union

I'm interested to know if a `UNION` is better than running *multiple queries*.

If so, are there times that multiple queries would be faster or preferred for other reasons?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- If you use `UNION ALL` and **don't sort** the output, then the
  performance of UNION should be more-or-less the same as the
  performance of multiple separate queries assuming the queries are
  identical to the ones you're `UNION`-ing together.
- If you use `UNION ALL` and **sort** the data, obviously you're imposing some overhead
  (although probably less than if you sorted in it your application).
- If you leave out the `ALL` keyword, MySQL will do the extra work of
  `DISTINCT`-ing your results. Again, this imposes extra overhead
  although probably less than doing it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You ask if it "is better" - I assume you are referring to "performance-wise"?

If the speed impact is minimal, you might want to prefer multiple queries to keep your code more readable; instead of dealing with multiple queries, doing different things, in one union.

Depends on the use case, for sure. But readable and understandable code might have it's worth in a bigger project in the long term

Comment: Thanks - yes, I'm meant is it more performant.  Readability of the code is not really a concern (for me..) because you can keep the queries separate and then at the code level join them with the "UNION" syntax or not.