# UNION vs multiple SELECT for getting previous and next row

Tags: php, mysql

This might be a duplicated question of [mysql union vs multiple queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979338/mysql-union-vs-multiple-queries) except the question is too general, and this question for specified case.

First of all, there are two options that I am thinking which one is better in term of 
performance wise. First one is getting previous and next row with separated query. The following is a pseudo code:

```
sql->query("SELECT * FROM tbldata WHERE id < 3 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
$prev = sql->getRecord();
sql->query("SELECT * FROM tbldata WHERE id > 3 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1");
$next = sql->getRecord();
```

Another solution is to use only one query with UNION.

```
sql->query("(SELECT * FROM tbldata WHERE id > 3 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) UNION
            (SELECT * FROM tbldata WHERE id < 3 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1)");
$row = sql->getRecords();
if (count($row) > 1) {
   $prev = $row[0];
   $next = $row[1];
} elseif (count($row) == 0) {
} elseif ($row[0]->id > 3) {
   $next = $row[0];
} else {
   $prev = $row[0];
}
```

Which one is a best practice for this type of problem?

Comment: Have a look at 
**MySQL - next / previous ID wih cycling**
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086267/mysql-next-previous-id-wih-cycling/17086521#17086521

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to guess, the UNION is probably faster overall, only because it reduces the number of requests to the database, but I stress, this is a guess and it will depend on many factors and the only way to know is to profile the code and check.

In reality, it probably makes very little difference. Unless there are unusual circumstances, like a very slow connection to the database server.

My suggestion would be, use whichever makes the code neater and easier to read until there is a reason to change it - ie. until your system profiling indicates that this is a bottleneck in the system.

Answer (score 1):

To my experience , I think `UNION` is faster than other one.

And Try this also.

```
SELECT * , IF( id >3, 1, 0 ) AS NextFlag, IF( id <3, 1, 0 ) AS PrevFlag FROM tbldata
WHERE id <= 3+1
HAVING NextFlag =1
OR PrevFlag =1
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 2
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql->query('SELECT t.*
             FROM table t
             WHERE t.id IN ('.($id-1).', '.($id+1).')');
$rows = sql->getRecords();

$next = $prev = false;

if (is_array($rows) && $rows) {
    $next = $rows[0];

    if (isset($rows[1])) {
        $prev = $rows[1];         
    } elseif ($rows[0]->id < $id) {
        $prev = $next;
        $next = false;
    }
}
```

One request with PRIMARY index (if id is your PRIMARY KEY). Better than UNION or 2 requests.

Comment: Primary keys are always sequential, isn't it? Of course you can always add ORDER BY t.id ASC.

Comment: Not if a row has been deleted.

Comment: ...and if you are not using autoincrement on your "id" field.